# Hide username and computer name from Git Bash for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, git-bash

[image]

Is there any way to remove the username and computer name from **Git Bash** for Window 10?

I already checked this : https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/199

But didn't understand how to do that.

Comment: Learn how to set the prompt in Bash.

Comment: @SLaks, could you please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Follow the steps below:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\` folder
2. Find and open the `git-prompt.sh` file in your favorite text editor
3. Go to line number **15**
4. Replace the whole line with `PS1="$PS1"''`
5. That's it. Start/Restart Git Bash and you should see the username and computer name is gone.

**NOTE:** You can also hide the annoying **MINGW64** text by commenting out the line number **16** and **17** of the same file. To comment out those lines just add a **#** to the beginning of the line. That's it. Now start/restart Git Bash and it should go away.

Comment: That's great, thank you! I just commented out lines 14-17, and that's it. Another Pro Tip: While most of the time I use bash in IDE's integrated terminal which is by default opened in the project folder, I also sometimes open it from the Taskbar shortcut. By default it opens in GitBash's folder is next to useless, so right-clicking the shortcut, choosing Properties and editing "Start in" value to "%userprofile%" did the trick to open in it "C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\".

Comment: All I want to add before PWD is what you'd get with `git config user.name` if in a Git repo. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

## Better way!!

Follow the steps as mentioned by @Saabbir, **with one big change:**

```sh
#  comment out the wrapping if-else block
if test -f ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
then
    . ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
else
  #  leave the content uncommented
  ...
fi
```

Save the file, `git-prompt.sh` using **Save As** (in your editor) in this path `C:\Users\{current_windows_user}\.config\git`

---

**Explanation:** You can see on line number 8 that it checks for the same file on `~/.config/git`. So it's better to update the config file rather than the actual settings file.

Comment: This leads to my Hyper with Git Bash crashing. Editing the original file works...

Comment: Hmm, not sure why this crash with Hyper. Well as long as you get it working, it's great.

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad That might be because in the new file you only need what is in the `else` block from line 12 till 36. If you duplicate the entire file, you migth end up with an endless loop.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks @OneManMonkeySquad